# Are there sufficient and necessary conditions for the existence of solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There are a lot of "existence theorem of solutions" for example,Peano existence theorem and Carathéodory's existence theorem. But they are not necessary conditions. 
For $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$,where $x,t \in R^n$ or more simply, when $n=1$, are there sufficient and necessary conditions for the existence of solutions to this differential equations? 
One thing to note is that the definition of the solution changes as needed, such as when $f$ is discontinuous to $x$ the definition of the solution given by Filippov need used, that is, the solution is defined using differential inclusion equations. 
I looked it up on google Scholar and couldn't find paper about it, or maybe I miss it?

Comment: Leaving aside statements that are both sufficient and necessary, any thoughts on just necessary conditions? Knowing an $x$ exists satisfying $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$, is there much we can say about $f$?

Comment: I just want to mention that Okamura's theorem talks about the necessary and sufficient conditions for the uniqueness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Other_existence_theorems.